# Copiar valor que esteja entre aspas C#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma `Textbox` que se encontra a ir buscar o texto a outro Form, e agora pretendo copiar um valor que se encontra nessa `Textbox`.

Imagem em anexo com o que pretendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ficou bem diferente do pedido inicialmente.. Para a próxima tenta ter mais atenção :P

Comment: Você está tendo dificuldades de implementar o que responderam nas respostas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa é o [método `String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), utilizado para extrair parte de uma *string*.

Para extrair somente o nome do arquivo, sem a extensão, use a função [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) do [namespace `System.IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx).

No evento `Click` do botão *Gerar* coloque o código:

```
string texto = textBox1.Text;
int valorPos = texto.IndexOf(@"""") + 1;
string valorEntreAspas = texto.Substring(valorPos, texto.IndexOf(@"""", valorPos) - valorPos);
string arquivoSemExtensao = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(valorEntreAspas);
label1.Text = arquivoSemExtensao;
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/q9O8GZ)

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito amigo, a funcionar! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Penso que a forma mais fácil é usar o [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) do C#, dividindo a string através das aspas.

```
string[] words = text.Split('"');
string[] parts = words[1].Split('.');
string result = parts[0];
```

o Split faz a divisão de uma string num array de strings utilizando o caracter " como separador. Depois é só ir ao array words, e nesse caso, ir buscar o index 1 do array, que deverá conter o nome que procura.

Comment: Amigo @BlunT podes ser mais específico?

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta BlunT.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana o Split é suficiente para fazer isso. Primeiro faz-se o split do texto original usando " como delimitador, e depois de obter a string que se pretende a partir do array resultante, faz-se split usando . como delimitador, e fica um array com 2 elementos, do qual o que interessa é o index 0.

Comment: Mas @BlunT, onde coloco esse código? Na Label? No Load? Estou em dúvida... Nem sei que código colocar, estou como se diz e bem "a apanhar do ar".

Comment: isso vai depender do código. se não fazes ideia do que estás a fazer é complicado...mas o sítio onde tens de colocar o código depende da forma como a aplicação está montada, e de como o texto está a ser introduzido na textbox

Comment: Imagina que é quando clico num button, qual o código que escrevo para na label aparecer o que está entre aspas.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana se a textbox se chama txt tens de fazer string[] parts = txt.Split('"'), depois usar o parts[1] para fazer Split('.') e depois dessa variavel que resulta, usar o indice 0, que devolve a string antes do ponto. vê a minha resposta editada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23899/discussion-between-godfathersantana-and-blunt).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar **Expressões Regulares** para encontrar o nome do arquivo no texto:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string texto = @"Isto é um exemplo. E quero que na label1 apareceça o que está dentro de aspas.
      Ou seja, o texto que se encontra ""aqui.txt"". 
      Porém a label1 não sabe o que estará na textbox.";

      var match = Regex.Match(texto, @"\""([\w\-. ]+)(\.)([\w\-. ]+)\""");
      string arquivoSemExtensao = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(match.Value.Replace("\"", String.Empty));

      Console.WriteLine(arquivoSemExtensao);     
    }      
}
```

[Veja funcionando aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwMoZb)

Se precisar encontrar mais de um nome de arquivo, basta alterar para usar o método `Matches` da classe `Regex`. Ela retorna uma coleção de valores encontrados no texto. Daí basta iterar e remover a extensão:

```
string texto = @"Isto é um exemplo. E quero que na label1 apareceça o que está dentro de aspas.
    Ou seja, o texto que se encontra ""aqui.txt"" ""teste.exe""  ""outro_arquivo.bat""
    Porém a label1 não sabe o que estará na textbox.";

var matches = Regex.Matches(texto, @"\""([\w\-. ]+)(\.)([\w\-. ]+)\""");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string arquivoSemExtensao = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(match.Value.Replace("\"", String.Empty));
    Console.WriteLine(arquivoSemExtensao);
}
```

[Exemplo aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bivPD6)

Comment: O utilizador não sabe o que estará escrito na Textbox amigo @MarcusVinicius.

Comment: Sim, por isso sugeri a utilização do Regex. Qualquer texto que entrar no textbox, se tiver o padrão de um nome de arquivo dentro de aspas, será capturado pela expressão. Só coloquei o texto fixo para exemplificar.

Comment: Então o que coloco em string texto = @".......";?

Comment: O valor do textbox: `nomeDoSeuTextBox.Text`