# Erro no SaveDialog c#

Tags: c#

Boas, tenho este excerto de código no C# e está tudo a funcionar, porém tenho um erro que ainda não consegui resolver, como podem ver na imagem e no código.
A label1 está a ir buscar texto a uma textbox, tal como podem ver aqui:

- [Copiar valor que esteja entre aspas C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64467/copiar-valor-que-esteja-entre-aspas-c?noredirect=1#comment132124_64467)

Só pretendo que apareça por exemplo o "M000050". Aquilo que está antes não interessa que apareça, pois não permite gravar.

**ERRO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SaveFileDialog salvar = new SaveFileDialog();
        salvar.FileName = label1 + ".cnf";
        salvar.Filter = "Ficheiro de Configuração|*.cnf";
        salvar.DefaultExt = "txt";
        DialogResult salvou = salvar.ShowDialog();
        (...)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere:

```
salvar.FileName = label1 + ".cnf";
```

Para:

```
salvar.FileName = label1.Text + ".cnf";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nem mais amigo, nem tinha detectado esse meu pequeno erro. Cumps